# Generating random numbers with Only integers, not floats

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have created a python script where I have 4 empty lists, and the code creates a random numbers on those lists, and in the end, it saves it as an Excel file. The issue is there that it creates numbers with floats, and I only want integers! Could somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import random

from openpyxl import Workbook

# Create workbook object
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()

sheet.title = 'Sheet #1'



# Generate data

Timestamp = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

Subtotal_vest = []

Subtotal_NorthEast = []

Subtotal_south = []

Others = []



for i in Timestamp:
    Subtotal_vest.append(random.gauss(3640, 25)),
    Subtotal_NorthEast.append(random.gauss(3832, 25)),
    Subtotal_south.append(random.gauss(2592, 25)),
    Others.append(random.gauss(1216, 25)),







#y = x * x

# Add titles in the first row of each column
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'Timestamp'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = 'Vest'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = 'North east'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=4).value = 'South'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=5).value = 'Others'

#sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = 'Y values'

# Loop to set the value of each cell

for inputs in range(0, len(Timestamp)):
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=1).value = Timestamp[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=2).value = Subtotal_vest[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=3).value = Subtotal_NorthEast[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=4).value = Subtotal_south[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=5).value = Others[inputs]



# Finally, save the file and give it a name
wb.save('Excel/Matrix.xlsx')
```

Comment: Do you want these numbers to be drawn from any particular distribution? There's [`np.random.randint()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) which draws from a discrete uniform distribution. Or perhaps [`np.random.poisson()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html)?

Comment: can you just use random.randint()

Comment: Thanks for answers guys! :), yes, I want to test different distributions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with random numbers drawn from a uniform distribution, you can use `random.randint` instead of `random.gauss`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip mate :)

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing this out there as another alternative. For an arbitrary distribution, you can create its cumulative distribution function (CDF) and then sample percentiles from this drawn from a uniform random distribution. You would then need to convert those to integers, but this gives you draws from any distribution that you want!

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Replace `mean` and `std` below with your existing means and standard deviations.
draw = norm.ppf(np.random.random(1000), loc=mean, scale=std)  # 1000 samples, for example
plt.hist(draw.astype(int))
```

A nice thing about this approach is that it works for any distribution for which you can create a CDF; even one that you can only define numerically from data!

Alternatively, you could approximate the normal distribution with the binomial distribution, which is discrete. In general, `B(n, p) ~ N(n*p, sqrt(n*p*(1-p)))`:

```
draw = np.random.binomial(n, p, size=1000)
```

You'd have to solve for `n` and `p` from your original mean and standard deviation by setting `n*p = mean` and `sqrt(n*p*(1-p)) = std`.

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively you can use [numpy.random.normal()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html):

```
import numpy as np

Timestamp = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
timestamps = len(Timestamp)

Subtotal_vest = np.random.normal(3640, 25, timestamps).astype(int)
Subtotal_NorthEast = np.random.normal(3832, 25, timestamps).astype(int)
Subtotal_south = np.random.normal(2592, 25, timestamps).astype(int)
Others = np.random.normal(1216, 25, timestamps).astype(int)
```

Comment: @Giroud2 You are welcome! Please accept the answer that you think answered your question the best

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `int(random.gauss(...))`?

Answer (score 0):

Cast to int the value returned by random.gauss will do:

```
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import random

from openpyxl import Workbook

# Create workbook object
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
sheet.title = 'Sheet #1'

# Generate data
timestamp = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 23
]
subtotal_vest = []
subtotal_north_east = []
subtotal_south = []
others = []

for i in timestamp:
    subtotal_vest.append(int(random.gauss(3640, 25))),
    subtotal_north_east.append(int(random.gauss(3832, 25))),
    subtotal_south.append(int(random.gauss(2592, 25))),
    others.append(int(random.gauss(1216, 25))),


#y = x * x

# Add titles in the first row of each column
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'Timestamp'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = 'Vest'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = 'North east'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=4).value = 'South'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=5).value = 'Others'

#sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = 'Y values'

# Loop to set the value of each cell

for inputs in range(0, len(timestamp)):
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=1).value = timestamp[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=2).value = subtotal_vest[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=3).value = subtotal_north_east[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=4).value = subtotal_south[inputs]
    sheet.cell(row=inputs + 2, column=5).value = others[inputs]

# Finally, save the file and give it a name
wb.save('Matrix.xlsx')
```

Comment: Same tip as the guy above! Thansk :) I love this forum!

Comment: @Giroud2 Hehe, well, i hadn't checked the other answers when posted, also, you can see with the attached code I'm using snake_case convention for variables, that way you follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: This code works fine and I get no errors, but It doesnt create any Excel file??

Comment: @Giroud2 Before posting it i've just checked and there should generate `Matrix.xlsx` with the right data, look at the final statement wb.save('Matrix.xlsx'). It should generate that file at the same folder than your python script :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Subtotal_vest = []

Subtotal_NorthEast = []

Subtotal_south = []

Others = []



for i in Timestamp:
    Subtotal_vest.append(random.gauss(3640, 25)),
    Subtotal_NorthEast.append(random.gauss(3832, 25)),
    Subtotal_south.append(random.gauss(2592, 25)),
    Others.append(random.gauss(1216, 25)),
```

with

```
Subtotal_vest = [int(round(random.gauss(3640, 25))) for _ in Timestamp]
Subtotal_NorthEast = [int(round(random.gauss(3832, 25))) for _ in Timestamp]
Subtotal_south = [int(round(random.gauss(2592, 25))) for _ in Timestamp]
Others = [int(round(random.gauss(1216, 25))) for _ in Timestamp]
```

`round` rounds to the nearest integer & then `int` converts the float to an integer.

Comment: I`ve also tried this and the code runs fine and no errors.. But it doesnt create any Excel file??

Comment: use the rest of your code to write to an excel file.

Comment: Ye now it works! Just didnt see that It was saved to another folder, so this code also works fine! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use int(rd.gauss(mu, sigma)).

David

Comment: Is it possible to import MU and sigma here as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.randint(0,10)` instead of `random.gauss`. random.randint() generate random integer values.

Comment: This is not a good suggestion. The values drawn will be uniform on `[0,10]` which is very different than `N(3640, 25)`.